# Photo Tag owner with Graph/FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

does anyone know how to (if possible) get the **owner** of the tag on a photo in facebook?

I can retrieve the tagged object id, text, coordinates and time on a photo (with Graph or FQL), but I don't know how to get id of the object that posted the tag.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not seem like this is something that facebook shares via the graph/fql api.

The [Image graph object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) has the *tags* connection which returns: *Tags with names and IDs*, and the [photo_tag fql table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/) has nothing about who created the tag (just the time).

Comment: Right. I was wondering if one could get this info from somewhere else. It's obvious that fb has this it just that it doesn't expose through the api I guess.

Comment: They might decide to share that in the future, though I doubt it, I think it's against privacy since even if you get permissions from the user to get his pics, who ever tagged them might not want you to know.

Comment: Kind of irrelevant as you can always see that information if you go on the web page and check the picture. Facebook _allways_ says who tagged who on the pic.

Comment: What facebook can do with the information they have is not the same as what you can do (as an app) with their info.